# Styling 'collection_radio_buttons'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, styles

Can I style these in such a way that a line break appears in between each radio button in a collection?

```
f.collection_radio_buttons(
  :chosen,
  [['A1', 1],['A2', 2], ['A3', 3]],
  :last,
  :first,
  html_options: { class: 'form-control' }
)
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is a duplicate @CheeseFry

Comment: how this is a duplicates? @CheeseFry

Comment: You could declare a css rule like `display: block` to that buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not able to test, but I think that this can help:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:chosen, [['A1', 1],['A2', 2], ['A3', 3]], :last, :first, html_options: { class: 'form-control' }) do |b| %>
    <%= b.label { b.radio_button + " " + b.text } %><br>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved it:

```
= residency.collection_radio_buttons :own,
    [[true, 'I Own This Home'], [nil, 'I Rent'], [false, 'I Live Rent Free']],
    :first,
    :last,
    item_wrapper_tag: :div, <-- MAGIC IS HERE
    label: false do |rdb|
      .d-block
        = rdb.radio_button + rdb.label(class: 'p-l-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the form_tag version allows customization via a block so I would assume the same applies to form_for

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons

> It's also possible to customize the way the elements will be shown by giving a block to the method:
>
> ```
> collection_radio_buttons(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b|
>   b.label { b.radio_button }
> end
> ```

So you could try something like this

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:chosen, [['A1', 1],['A2', 2], ['A3', 3]], :last, :first, html_options: { class: 'form-control' }) do |b| %>
  <%= b.label { b.radio_button } %><br>
<% end %>
```